# Bug in Flutter, while editing text in RTL languages

Tags: android, flutter, right-to-left, flutter-widget, text-direction

There is a bug in Flutter while using RTL (Right To Left) TextField.
If we click on (A), the cursor will stop at B, one before the end of the text, and we can't edit the last character!
I created this issue and I hope Flutter people see it and fix it

[image]

Comment: can you provide a link to your posted issue?

Answer (score 5):

I solve this bug ..

in your TextField you should use controller and onTab function write

```
if (textController.selection ==
                            TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(
                                offset:
                                    textController.text.length -
                                        1))) {
                          textController.selection =
                              TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(
                                  offset: textController.text.length));
                        }
```

full example like

```
   TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      controller:textController,
                      maxLength: 10,
                      onTap: () {
                        if (textController.selection ==
                            TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(
                                offset:
                                    textController.text.length -
                                        1))) {
                          textController.selection =
                              TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(
                                  offset:textController.text.length));
                        }
                      },
                      onChanged: (text) {  },
             );
```